# char representation in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have a char array of asciiname[]= "NUL\0" " SP\0" "  P\0" .......` and so on;
than I have following code

```
while ((c = getchar()) !=EOF){
    for (i=0; i<128; ++i) {
        if (c == asciiname[i])
            printf("The code %3x represents %s\n", i, &asciiname[4*i]);
    }
}
```

if statement never returns true. Obviously there is something wrong with the statement. Can't wrap my head around it. asciiname is a char array (1 bite per element) but it still takes what seems to me as a string `"NUL\0"` how is that possible?  What value of `asciiname[i]` is evaluated in `if (c == asciiname[i])`?? **Any help is strongly appreciated!!!**

update::: there is only one char asciname[]... sorry for mistyping. My goal is to create visible typewriter using only stdio library. Basically I've been given a file and i have to read it ind generate output one char per line. The plan is to get char c from input, find it in asciiname array and print it out. The code is the format that i have to follow. The problem is my if statement never returns true. I don't understand logic of internal representation of char array.... I've been reading a lot, without any luck. please explain

UPDATE: I got it all figured out. Thank all of you for attention and swift responses!!! this site rock!!!

Comment: What is `asciiname`???

Comment: So what to you expect to get in `c`? How do you know that you are getting any of the chars that appear in `ASCIName`?

Comment: @Ben: The `if` statement does not refer to `ASCIName`.

Comment: `C` identifiers are CaSe SeNsItIvE.

Comment: `c == i` instead of `c == asciiname[i]`

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The difference between `ASCIName` and `asciiname` does not come down to case-sensitivity. They appear to be two different symbols.

Comment: @barakmanos might be a bad idea, but i made the assumption here that `ASCInames` and `asciiname` are the same thing ... just typed it differently in the question and the code?

Comment: Any way, this question is not clear ... We need more details about what you are trying to do. What is your input and expected result?

Comment: @Ben: **Very** differently.

Comment: @barakmanos same thought as @ ben

Comment: @SouravGhosh: If you have the same thought, then your comment about case-sensitivity is irrelevant.

Comment: @barakmanos I did not get you. I was saying `ASCInames` and `asciiname` are not the same thing. What is your point?

Comment: Both are very likely **meant** to be the same array (note the `* 4` in the code). Of course they are actually **not**. Wish my computer would do what I want, not what I write - sometimes.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: If you agree with Ben's assumption (which now makes a little more sense to me as well), then you believe that the array in the actual code is the "right one", and that `ASCInames` is just a typo in the description. Hence case-sensitivity is not the issue here.

Comment: @Olaf Thank god someone understood. uff. English is not my native language and sometimes I do a horrible job in explaining myself. :-(

Comment: @barakmanos I did not say that is a _real_ issue, was just posting a "comment" for general info.

Comment: there is only one char asciname[]... sorry for mistyping. My goal is to create visible typewriter using only stdio library. Basically I've been given a file and i have to read it ind generate output one char per line. The plan is to get char c from input, find it in asciiname array and print it out. The code is the format that i have to follow. The problem is my if statement never returns true. I don't understand logic of internal representation of char array.... I've been reading a lot, without any luck. please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar()` returns a char cast to an int. If you have the value of c, then you should be able to reference `asciiname` just by saying `asciiname[c]`. You don't need to use a for-loop because you have exactly the index that you need.

For example, `asciiname[0]` would evaluate to `"NUL\0", asciiname[1]` would evaluate to `"SP\0"` and so on.

Comment: Woh Woh Woh, this wont work!!! `getchar` will return you a char, for example `a` when converted to an `int` this will be 97. If you do `asciiname['a'] (which ==) asciiname[97]`, you will just be getting the 97th element, i dont think this is what you want to do! What if the ascii value is larger then your array is long!?

Comment: @Ben - Judging from the range of the for-loop it seems that asciiname has 128 elements. If not, then that would certainly be cause for concern, but as elements 0 through 127 were already being accessed safely I would assume that asciiname has a reasonable length.